# jquery logic related to kendo

Tags: jquery, kendo-combobox

I have two kendoComboBoxes, in the js file (jquery) both are reffering same column from database.  After selecting value from first kendocombobox, values in other kendocombobox should display values greater than the selected value in first.
Can any one help with the jquery logic. Thanks in advance.

Comment: post the code also. may be you can use jsfiddle

Comment: sounds like you need to use the cascade from approach. check this demo out: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/combobox/cascadingcombobox